# Javascript rotating banner - Initial BG Colour change

Tags: javascript, banner, rotation

I'm currently using the Dynamic drive java script code for a rotating banner on one of our company websites.

The problem I'm having is that the initial background colour for the banner when loading into the page is pure black, and I'm struggling to find where I can change that.

example website: http://www.sakawater.com

You'll notice the initial BG is black, going to white - which does not look great.

The javascript comes from : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

I've not modified much apart from the scale of the banner and fade speed, can someone point me in the right direction on how to fix/change the initial loading background colour please? Or how to remove having a BG for that at all.

Thank you,

Navson

Answer (score 1):

in `fadeslideshow.js` Try to search `gallerylayer` and you will see this line:

```
setting.$gallerylayers=$('<div class="gallerylayer"></div><div class="gallerylayer"></div>') //two stacked DIVs to display the actual slide 
        .css({position:'absolute', left:0, top:0, width:'100%', height:'100%', background:'black'})
```

Here you will see the color black, change it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, 

Much appreciated